# How to Copy Text to clipboard upon echo with PHP & JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo, clipboard

apologies if this sounds super stupid.

I've spent some time trying to do this, and the only way I've found is after clicking something like a button.

I have a form for generating license keys and I would like to copy license key to clipboard after generation, so I'd like to know if there's some JavaScript code that I can echo to make this work, so far I've had no luck with the below code:

```php
<?php
echo
'<script>
var e = "texttocopy";
            var tempItem = document.createElement(\'input\');
            tempItem.setAttribute(\'type\',\'text\');
            tempItem.setAttribute(\'display\',\'none\');
            let content = e;
            if (e instanceof HTMLElement) {
                    content = e.innerHTML;
            }
            tempItem.setAttribute(\'value\',content);
            document.body.appendChild(tempItem);
            tempItem.select();
            document.execCommand(\'Copy\');
            tempItem.parentElement.removeChild(tempItem);
            alert("Successfully copied the key to your clipboard!");
}
            </script>';
?>
```

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`navigator.clipboard.writeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText).

```
<script>
navigator.clipboard.writeText('texttocopy');
</script>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much <3 in 5 minutes I have the ability to accept your answer, and I will. I appreciate your help man.

Comment: @hugzho Happy to help.